# Android Custom Dialog show/hide on Menu press

Tags: android, menu, dialog

I have a custom dialog and use it instead of optionMenu. So I want myDialog to behave like menu, i.e. show/hide on Menu press. I've tried many variants, but had the same result:

as I set an OnKeyListener for myDialog

```
myDialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            if (arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
                                    myActivity.this.removeDialog(ID);
                                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

so every time dialog is created by Menu press, it immediately hides by that Listener.

Are there any ideas to make my dialog work with Menu button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.help:
    // ... etc, etc.
}
```

/res/menu/menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="Help" />
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About" />
    <item android:id="@+id/prefs"
            android:title="Preferences" />
</menu>
```

Comment: and how does this help? LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
what's this suppose to do, just a pointless initialization ?